# Active Navigation Bar when go to another page

Tags: html, css

I want to ask how to make active navbar when I go to another page. Below is my header.html code:

```
<header>
    <div class="w3-top top" id="header">
        <div class="w3-bar w3-red" >
            <img src='Images\menubar-logo-white.png' width="150" height="50">
            <div class="w3-right topnav " id="myTopnav">
                <a href="home.html" onclick="redirect(this.href)" class="btn active w3-hide-small">HOME</a>
                <a href="about.html" onclick="redirect(this.href)" class="btn">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="service.html" onclick="redirect(this.href)" class="btn">SERVICES</a>
                <a href="contact.html" onclick="redirect(this.href)" class="btn">CONTACT</a>

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:20px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</header>
```

And the script:

```
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }

    function redirect(page) {
        window.parent.location = page;
    }
```

FYI, I only have one navbar page and I include the header.html into multiple pages. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by active?

Comment: like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element

Comment: The example you provided on w3schools is doing exactly what you asked for, what is the problem using it?

Comment: but it does not work for me